# Setting logonHours property to lock unlock user accounts

Tags: active-directory

How do I set each bit of the logonHours property (which as 21 bytes) to either zero (for locking user account) or one (for unlocking) ? I have obtained the logonHours property in bytes as follows:

```
bytes[] logonHours = (byte[])de.Properties["logonHours"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//After seaching the web, I used the following code :

```
public void myMethod(String p_UserName)
  {
       byte[] logonHours = null;

       logonHours = (byte[])de.Properties["logonHours"].Value;
       BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(logonHours);

        for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Count; i++)
        {
            //If bit is zero (that is false), logonHours is Locked
            //If bit is one (that is true) then set to zero (false) to LOCK the account
            if (bitArray[i])
            {
                bitArray.Set(i, false);
            }
        }

        byte[] m_Bytes1 = MyExtension.ConvertToByteArray(bitArray);


        de.Properties["logonHours"].Value = m_Bytes;
        de.CommitChanges();

   }
```

static class MyExtension
   {

```
 public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(this BitArray bits)
   {
       int numBytes = bits.Count / 8;
       if (bits.Count % 8 != 0) numBytes++;

       byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];
       int byteIndex = 0, bitIndex = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++)
       {
           if (bits[i])
               bytes[byteIndex] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - bitIndex));

           bitIndex++;
           if (bitIndex == 8)
           {
               bitIndex = 0;
               byteIndex++;
           }
       }

       return bytes;
   }//end of method
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that can help you : [Active Directory Permitted Logon Times with C#](http://anlai.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/active-directory-permitted-logon-times-with-c-net-3-5-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement/)